# Call to a member function getQuery() on null symfony

Tags: symfony, query-builder, easyadmin

I'm following this tuto about CSV export on EasyAdmin bundle in symfony ([link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/csv-export))
and I'm stuck at this point:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createListQueryBuilder(

        Employee::class,
        $sortDirection,
        $this->request->query->get('sortField'),
        $this->entity['list']['dql_filter']
    );
        return $this->csvExporter->getResponseFromQueryBuilder(
        $queryBuilder,
        Employee::class,
        'employees.csv'
    );
```

UPDATE: 
I'm overwriting the method createListQueryBuilder

```
protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null   , $dqlFilter = null){}
```

and in the csvExporter i'm defining a function getResponseFormQueryBuilder

```
public function getResponseFromQueryBuilder(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, $columns, $filename)
```

I'm having a bug that says that:

`Expected parameter of type '\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder', 'void' provided`

Comment: Show the whole function please. Your calling a function which has a parameter requirement of `QueryBuilder $queryBuilder` and your providing something with value `void`.

Comment: check the update please @rkeet

Comment: Hmm yes, well, if you use Xdebug you'd see that `$queryBuilder === null` evaluates to true probably. The function `$this->createListQueryBuilder(...)` is not returning what you expect. As such the subsequent `*->getResponseFromQueryBuilder(...)` call fails on a non-received value.

Comment: what should i do (sorry i'm a beginner)

Comment: Follow the instructions for [installation of Xdebug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html) (check your needed version [here](https://xdebug.org/wizard)), then set breakpoints in your code and step through line by line to see what's not working correctly ;-) If you want to take the manual route, set and declare each variable outside of the function call separately and `var_dump` (or how you like to do it) to the front-end to check values. So: `$class = Employee::class` then use `$this->createListQueryBuilder($class, ...)` (example) - xdebug = better though - faster

Comment: the bug is when i override the function createListQueryBuilder

Comment: i define an empty funtion  [  protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null   , $dqlFilter = null){} ] and then i populate in another class is this wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

i was overwriting the wrong funtion 
you should define it like this (before you overwrite it)

> ```
> protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
> /**
>  * Performs a database query based on the search query provided by the user.
>  * It supports pagination and field sorting.
>  *
>  * @param string      $entityClass
>  * @param string      $searchQuery
>  * @param array       $searchableFields
>  * @param int         $page
>  * @param int         $maxPerPage
>  * @param string|null $sortField
>  * @param string|null $sortDirection
>  * @param string|null $dqlFilter
>  *
>  * @return Pagerfanta The paginated query results
>  */    {
>     return $this->get('easyadmin.query_builder')->createListQueryBuilder($this->entity, $sortField, $sortDirection, $dqlFilter);
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

you should make sure `$queryBuilder` is type of `QueryBuilder` , I advise you to trace debug `$queryBuilder` variable before return line and detect why it's void.